# Sum of Squares using Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to carry out the following computation:
sum of the squares of integers in the range x:y where (x <= y).

I'm not sure how to put a constraint to ensure x is less than or equal to y.

I need to be able to add the square of x to the sum of squares in the range x+1:y.

I've had a look at a few examples but cannot find any which strictly say the first number must be less than or equal to the second number i.e. [1..5]

UPDATE: Just to clarify, I do not want to hard code [1..5] in the function but I want the list to be an input from the user.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Well have you actually tried `[1 .. 5]`?

Comment: `sum $ map (^2) [x..y]`?

Comment: If you mean that you want `f x y == f y x`, then just do `f x y = sum $ map (^2) [min x y .. max x y]`

Comment: I think you would need type level natural numbers to statically check that two integral values are well ordered (it's quite complicated, but it's doable for just an ordering relation between literals). Otherwise, you can simply make your code swap the values if they're not in the right order (or raise an error?).

Comment: yes, i want to be able to say if the first value is less than second value then it should error. How would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Slow approach

The obvious and slow approach is to actually sum those squares:

```
sumOfSquaresSlow :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
sumOfSquaresSlow lo hi
    | lo > hi   = error "sumOfSquaresSlow: lo > hi"
    | otherwise = sum $ map (^2) [lo..hi]
```

The time complexity of this approach is linear in max(y-x,0); it will take a while if your range of integers is large; see the benchmark at the bottom of my answer.

### Faster approach

However, because there is a [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number#Formula) for the sum of the squares of the first n (positive) integers, you don't actually have to sum those squares one by one.

To issue an error message to the user in case `x` is greater that `y` (as specified in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407773/sum-of-squares-using-haskell/27408712#comment43264073_27407773)), you can simply use the `error` function, here.

(**Edit**: thanks to Chris Drost for [pointing out that I was overcomplicating things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407773/sum-of-squares-using-haskell/27408712#comment43296741_27408712))

```
sumOfSquaresFast :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
sumOfSquaresFast lo hi
    | lo > hi   = error "sumOfSquaresFast: lo > hi"
    | otherwise = ssq hi - ssq (lo - 1)
  where
    ssq x = div (((2 * x + 3) * x + 1) * x) 6
```

Using this formula instead reduces the complexity to something close to constant time.

### Benchmark in GHCi

```
λ> :set +s

λ> sumOfSquaresSlow (10^3)  (10^7)
333333383333002166500
(17.19 secs, 11563005552 bytes)

λ> sumOfSquaresFast (10^3) (10^7)
333333383333002166500
(0.01 secs, 3106112 bytes)
```

Comment: I apologize for being super-negative, but: (1) Ratio is totally unnecessary, distracting, and complicates your type signature. (2) You didn't raise the error in the first case, which is the actual answer. The second answer is premature optimization given the numbers specified; if we're teaching at this level we want clarity-of-expression first. (3) All of the signum stuff is totally unnecessary. `sumOfSquares a b = let ssq x = div (2 * x^3 + 3 * x^2 + x) 6 in if a <= b then ssq b - ssq (a - 1) else error "sum of squares: b > a"` is sufficient.

Comment: @ChrisDrost No need to apologize; constructive criticism is always welcome. 1) You're right; I'm just realising now that I can do everthing with `div`. 2) I did forget to raise the error in the first approach. The second approach is indeed overkill for `[1..5]`, but how large a range the function is supposed to gracefully handle is unclear, which is why I suggested a faster approach. 3) Yes; point taken.

Answer (score 2):

In GHCI do these steps to see what's going on:

```
Prelude> let sq x = x^2
Prelude> let list = [1..5]
Prelude> list
[1,2,3,4,5]
Prelude> let listOfSq = map sq list
Prelude> listOfSq
[1,4,9,16,25]

Prelude> sum listOfSq
55
```

The shorthand would be exactly what Jubobs suggested:

```
sum $ map (^2) [1..5]
```

EDIT: To error out when Y is greater than X you can do something like this

```
sumOfSquares :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
sumOfSquares x y  | y <= x = error "Y must be greater than X"
                  | otherwise = sum $ map (^2) [x..y]
```

Comment: thanks. I have something similar however I'm looking to let the user give in the list values instead of hard coding them myself. any suggestions?

Comment: define your function like so: `sumOfSquares list = sum $ map (^2) list` and call it like so: `sumOfSquares [x..y]` where you get the values x and y from the user.

Comment: that works fine however i still cant code the constraint of x needing to be less than or equal to y :/

Comment: You can simply call `error` if your inputs are bad.  see my edit

Answer (score -1):

Using list comprehension:

```
squareSum from to
  | from > to = error "wrong input"
  | otherwise = sum [i^2 | i <- [from..to]]
```

UPDATE: updated after OP has updated the question