# sum of square integers haskell

Tags: haskell, integer

I have this code to work out the sum of squares of integers in the range of m:n

```
sumsquares :: Integral a=> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
sumsquares m n middle
 | m > n = error "First number cannot be bigger than second number"
 |m==n = m*m
 |otherwise = m*m + sumsquares (m+1)n
```

How would i redefine the function sumsquares for this purpose?

If there is more than one number in the range m:n, compute the middle of the range and add the sum of the squares of (m:middle) to sum of the squares (middle+1:n),
otherwise there is only one number in the range m:n, so m = = n, and the solution is just the square of m. (Note that with this approach the recursion combines two half- solutions: each sub-problem is approximately half in size of the overall problem).

Comment: I don't understand what you need middle for....  You aren't using it, and from your description of how I think you want to use it, it doesn't save anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum of Squares using Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407773/sum-of-squares-using-haskell)

Comment: I guess it's not a duplicate as the question is asking for a different solution structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your original function, the class constraint `Integral a` in the type signature is obsolete (`a` is not mentioned anywhere else in the signature, is it?). Furthermore, the third parameter of the function (`middle`) remains unused. Hence, you could have written it as

```
sumsquares :: Int -> Int -> Int 
sumsquares m n  
  | m > n     = error "First number cannot be bigger than second number"
  | m == n    = m * m
  | otherwise = m * m + sumsquares (m + 1) n
```

Rewriting it to move from a [decrease-and-conquer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms#Decrease_and_conquer) scheme to a strict divide-and-conquer scheme then just involves adapting the recursive case accordingly:

```
sumsquares :: Int -> Int -> Int 
sumsquares m n  
  | m > n     = error "First number cannot be bigger than second number"
  | m == n    = m * m
  | otherwise = let middle = (m + n) `div` 2
                in  sumsquares m middle + sumsquares (middle + 1) n
```

The question remains, of course, why you would want to make this change. One reason could be that you are preparing your algorithm to be adapted for parallelisation: then, indeed, divide-and-conquer  is often a better fit than decrease-and-conquer.

Comment: ahhh i can see what you mean, how would i use a trace to show its computation?

Comment: @Harry Lists, however, parallelize badly, so you will only gain something from doing so if each calculation is expensive. That's not the case here, so the fastest way to sum the squares of the elements of a list is just to do it in order, one by one.

Comment: @dfeuer One can also gain if there are many inexpensive computations happening. Note that I was not suggesting that every multiplication is executed in its own thread. If you have enough multiplications to assign to a thread, the gains from parallelisation may still outweigh the induced overhead.

Comment: @StefanHoldermans, I think that would hold for many cheap computations in an `Array`, `Vector`, `ByteString`, `Text`, `Sequence`, etc., but summing the squares of elements of a *list*, the task of following all the pointers to traverse the list is quite a large part of the work, and using multiple threads won't help that any.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes, but in this example, there are no lists.

Comment: Wow, I must be even more tired than I realized. That was boneheaded.