# Haskell - Square everything in list

Tags: haskell

I am trying to find the sum of squares of everything in a list, for example :

```
[1,2,3] --> 1+4+9 --> 14
```

Here is my attempt:

```
sqSum :: (a->a)->[a]->a
sqSum _ [] = 0
sqSum f (x:xs) = f x + sqSum f xs

square :: Int->Int
square num = num*num
```

I use it as so...

```
sqSum square [1,2,3]
```

But I get an error:

```
square.hs:2:14:
    No instance for (Num a) arising from the literal `0'
    Possible fix:
      add (Num a) to the context of
        the type signature for sqSum :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> a
    In the expression: 0
    In an equation for `sqSum': sqSum _ [] = 0
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: What's wrong with just using `sum . map (^2)`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407773/sum-of-squares-using-haskell

Comment: Why do you want `sqSum` to take a function as an argument?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you're saying that the type of `sqSum` is `(a->a)->[a]->a`, in other words, that it can operate on any type of data.

You then go on to say that the empty list gives a result of `0`. This is valid when the type is a number, but not when the type is a String, tuple or function.

You can specify that your function is only supposed to work for numbers by adding a class constraint in the type signature:

```
sqSum :: Num a => (a->a)->[a]->a
sqSum _ [] = 0
sqSum f (x:xs) = f x + sqSum f xs

square :: Int->Int
square num = num*num
```

---

You can also take it a step further by decoupling the input type from the output type, and saying that you can accept a list of any type, as long as you have a function to convert it to a number to be summed:

```
sqSum :: Num b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> b
```

Now you can do both `sqSum square [1,2,3]` and `sqSum length ["a", "be", "sea"]`.

Oh, and instead of hard coding `+` and `0`, you can pass in a combiner function and a zero value:

```
sqSum :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
sqSum _ zero [] = zero
sqSum f zero (a:rest) a `f` sqSum f zero rest
```

Now you can start from zero and add all the squares using

```
sqSum ((+) . square) 0 [1,2,3]
```

Or start from `1` and multiply all the squares using

```
sqSum ((*) . square) 1 [1,2,3]
```

Or start from empty string and concatenate all the numbers using

```
sqSum ((++) . show) "" [1,2,3]
```

This version of `sqSum` already exists in the standard libraries, and is called `foldr`.