# Creating a haskell function that returns the sum of the squares in a list of lists of ints?

Tags: haskell

I'm currently working on a small practice question for a haskell course I have. It asks the following:

> Write a Haskell function called sumSquareMax which takes a list of lists of Ints as a parameter,
>   finds the maximum of each sub-list and returns the sum the squares of those maximums.

I've figured out how to do it using individual lines of code in the win hugs compiler but I really want to make it a simple function with parameters. What I have so far is as follows:

```
sumSquaresMax :: [[Int]] -> Int
sumSquaresMax x
    let maxes = map maximum x
    let squares = map (^2) maxes
    let finalSum = sum squares
```

So if I were to run `sumSquaresMax [[4,2,5],[6,2],[2],[-6,4,1]]` first it would map the maximum of the lists: `[5,6,2,4]` then, it would square each of these numbers and then sum the squares leading to my answer.

How would I go about "printing" `finalSum`? I know this is not even close to being correct but I'm not entirely sure where to go from here. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "I've figured out how to do it using individual lines of code in the win hugs compiler" - Hugs hasn't been maintained for a number of years, I'd recommend switching to GHC/GHCi.

Comment: @bheklilr we both know that he probably has no choice here ;)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407773/sum-of-squares-using-haskell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only have one `let` statement in your example function if I understand your example. (While you can have multiple `let` statements, this isn't how you do it). `let` gives you the ability to define functions within a function, things that are one-off pieces of code you won't use elsewhere.

When you use `let`, you have to also include `in` to provide the actual return value of the function.

You are also missing the `=` sign for defining your function body.

Here's what I think you're trying to do:

```haskell
sumSquaresMax :: [[Int]] -> Int
sumSquaresMax x = 
    let maxes = map maximum x
        squares = map (^2) maxes
    in sum squares
```

Comment: of course you can have more than one `let` - for example: `f x = let y = x+5 in let z = y+6 in z` is a perfectly fine expression - yours indeed is just a shorter syntactic sugar to this

Comment: Sure, I was just trying to be succinct. I've updated it to make it a little more clear.

Answer (score 2):

you actually have it there - all you have to do is replacing names:

```
sumSquaresMax x
= sum squares
= sum (map (^2) maxes)
= sum (map (^2) (map maximum x))
= sum . map (^2) . map maximum $ x
= sum . map ((^2) . maximum) $ x
```

so overall:

```
sumSquaresMax = sum . map ((^2) . maximum)
```

example:

```
Prelude> let sumSquaresMax = sum . map ((^2) . maximum)
Prelude> sumSquaresMax [[4,2,5],[6,2],[2],[-6,4,1]]
81
```